# Restful routing not loading assets Laravel 4.1

Tags: rest, laravel-4

I'm using restful routing `Route::resource()` and am running into this problem where I specify the restful route to redirect to, but it loads my view without displaying the styles in my stylesheets. I can see that they've been loaded but no style is applied.

I have 3 routes including the 7 restful routes that are made by `resource()`:

```
Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');
Route::get('logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');
```

In SessionsController a create a session like so:

```
public function create()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
        //views/sessions/create.blade.php
        return View::make('sessions.create');
    }
```

And destroyed by redirecting back to the above create method:

```
public function destroy()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        //if you're referencing a restful route, use redirect::route(), not redirect::to()
        return Redirect::route('sessions.create');
    }
```

But when I redirect to that route when destroyed the session, I get shown my view without styling applied to it. If I call `Redirect::to('login')` in `destroy()` it loads my full view, but I don't know why it doesn't work properly when calling the route by name.

I'm extending a master layout page which only yields my content and loads stylesheets.

Just to be clear, it only happens when I call the destroy() function, if I go to 'login' it loads my view with styles, otherwise not. i.e. `sessions/create` won't load with styles

Is giving an alias to routes overwriting the defaults?

Edit:

Here are the styles being loaded in my template:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    @yield('login-styles')
```

and I'm setting login-styles like this from the create.blade.php view:

```
@section('login-styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login-style.css">
@stop
```

Comment: Likely has nothing to do with your named routes, and more about the path to your CSS. You should show your view/layout code, particularly the header CSS info.

Comment: When I try to run the sessions routes through the uri like 'sessions/create', the view isn't loaded with styles, but using 'public/login' loads them. I don't think it has to do with how I'm loading my css files

Comment: I read this: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil, I'm probably just going to manually declare my routes instead of using route::resources()

Comment: How you create your routes has nothing to do with your CSS being loaded, unless you're creating a dynamic route specifically *for* your CSS. You're using relative URLs for your assets, which will change depending on what URI you're currently viewing. Read up about it. Change your links to something like `href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}"` instead.

Comment: @Cryode I'm finding out (slowly) that you _have_ to use Laravels helper functions if you want your site to run. Even though I've decided not to use restful controllers, your answer helped me in another way. Thanks for sharing that tip

Comment: Actually it's much like CodeIgniter, having to specify 'base_url()' in your paths alot

Comment: You don't *have* to use anything. Doing so just makes your life easier. You don't have to worry about relative URLs, or moving your application to a new domain, etc.